# Display json format with Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I am trying to display an object that had been imported to blender with stl format and i exported to json format by this [exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender). Below is the json file

```
{
"normals" :[....]
"metadata": {
    "normals": 2673,
    "vertices": 2972,
    "faces": 5380,
    "uvs": 0,
    "type": "Geometry",
    "version": 3,
    "generator": "io_three"
},
"name": "ForenBox demoGeometry",
"vertices": [....]
"faces": [...]
"uvs": []
```

}

My js loader works fine beacause i tested it with correct json formats.
What is mine json format missing?

The object has been imported to blender by stl format!

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us more of your code? what does your three.js project look like?

Comment: Hey! I just figured it out. In the export of blender i ticked the face materials option and it works fine! Thanks anyway